# widely adopted tool for Markdown Editor

Tags: web, markdown

I need to integrate a Markdown editor for a Vue web application. I use GitLab on a daily basis and was thinking of doing the same thing.

But I haven't found the source code and searching on the internet, I don't have the impression that there is an open source consensus on a specific tool.

I found https://github.com/Ionaru/easy-markdown-editor who can do it.

So **my question** is the following: is there really no widely adopted Markdown editor when Markdown is used in so many web applications?